# when i put Achor tag dynamic URL it converts badly

Tags: c#, asp.net, ckeditor

i'm putting html in ckeditor as

```
 <li><a href="<%#ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Path"].ToString()%>Default">Home</a></li>
```

but it converts it to something like ,

```
<li><a a="" href="&lt;%#ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a></li>
```

what i do ?

Comment: When you say `putting html in ckeditor` can you explain what you mean by that? What file are you putting that in, for example?

Comment: I thought ckeditor was a javascript rich text editor. It seems like it's escaping your text. But, why are you using this for creating asp.net mark up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Locate *config.js* and inside ckEditor config section add/replace following:

```
//Whether to escape HTML when the editor updates the original input element.   
config.htmlEncodeOutput = false; 

//Whether to use HTML entities in the editor output.
config.entities = false; 

//Whether to escape basic HTML entities in the document
config.basicEntities = false;
```

Source: [Check Docs](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config)